# Multiple HDInsight clusters with single ADLS gen2 storage

Tags: azure-hdinsight

I'm trying to create multiple HDInsight clusters on single ADLS gen2 storage. Found [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-multiple-clusters-data-lake-store) "Use multiple HDInsight clusters with an Azure Data Lake Storage account", created folders on filesystem, but unable to specify folder path in Filesystem textbox.

[image]

How should I specify folder path for cluster ?

UPDATE1: To be specific, I'm trying to reproduce this recommendation from documentation
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> While creating a HDInsight cluster storage accounts - it is **only allowed to create or select container level** only like `dev-fs`.

Note: **It's not allowed to select sub-directories** under any container like `dev-fs/clusters/mr-cluster`

[image]

If you want to create a multiple HDInsight cluster in one single ADLS gen2 account, you can try to create multiple containers inside the ADLS gen2 account.

**Example:** I want to create two HDInsight cluster with same ADLS gen2 account, you should use the below format.

> Azure HDInsight `clusterone` with ADLS gen2 storage account container named `hdinsight-clusterone`.

[image]

> Azure HDInsight `clustertwo` with ADLS gen2 storage account container named `hdinsight-clustertwo`.

[image]

> Best practices while using multiple HDInsight clusters in a single ADLS gen2 storage account:

We don't recommend that you use the default blob container for storing business data. Deleting the default blob container after each use to reduce storage cost is a good practice. The default container contains application and system logs. Make sure to retrieve the logs before deleting the container.

**Note:** Sharing one blob container as the default file system for multiple clusters isn't supported.

For more details, refer to [Use Azure storage with Azure HDInsight clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage).

Comment: Not sure I understand you. In mentioned article written that best way - subfolders:
Consider you have a Data Lake Storage account with the folder structure /clusters/finance. With this structure, all the clusters required by the Finance organization can use /clusters/finance as the storage location.
I need to configure 3 clusters sharing data:  MR and Spark clusters writing data, Hive cluster allow to access data via jdbc.  As I understand, multiple containers will not allow me to put data in one storage.

Comment: I would be glad to get any hint regarding to article folder structure